# Add custom field to taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I added a custom field to a taxonomy term via 'Manage Fields' (see screenshot here: https://cl.ly/022v2B2H2c1m). How can I display this new field in the Frontend? In my template.php I have this:

```
$cats = taxonomy_get_tree(7);
$categories = array();
if (!empty($cats)) {
  foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $parent = $cat->parents[0];
    $item = array(
      'tid' => $cat->tid,
      'name' => $cat->name,
      'description' => $cat->description,
      'image' => $cat->field_images,
      'children' => array(),
    );

  }
}
```

When I do a var_dump($item), the image field shows 'NULL', although I added an image.

Anybody with a solution?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$field_image = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_image');
if ($field_image) {
  $headerimg = field_view_value('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_image', $field_image[0], array('type' => 'image'));
}
print render($headerimg);
```

In your file `template.php` use the `theme_preprocess_page` function like this :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
  if ($term) {
    $field_header_image = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image');
    if ($field_header_image) {
      $vars['headerimg'] = field_view_value('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_header_image', $field_header_image[0], array('type' => 'image'));
    }
  }
}
```

Then in you `page.tpl.php` you can print `render($headerimg);`